# Background images with asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

This should be a simple thing but for some reason it won't work.

I'm having trouble getting a background image displayed on my page. I'm using Rails 3.2 with the asset pipeline. I am trying to display it on pages related to my **home** controller.

The image location is: **app/assets/images/dna.jpg**

**home.css.scss**

```
background: url('/assets/images/dna.jpg');
```

I've also tried the following:

```
background: url('dna.jpg');
background: url('/assets/dna.jpg');
background-image: image-url("dna.jpg");
background-image:url(image_path('dna.jpg'));
```

Regardless of which approach I try, I get the same error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /
Invalid CSS after "background:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was "   url('/assets/i..."
```

(in /Users/sean/Dropbox/bin/rails/assay/app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss)

See also this SO post: [Adding a background image in Ruby on Rails 2 in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024252/adding-a-background-image-in-ruby-on-rails-in-css)

**EDIT**

Referring to this post: [sass-rails asset pipeline: generating image paths incorrectly; `url(/images/blah.png)` instead of `url(/assets/blah.png)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040366/sass-rails-asset-pipeline-generating-image-paths-incorrectly-url-images-blah?rq=1)

I cleared the asset cache

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

And bundle updated my **sass-rails** gem. It's at 3.2.6 now. 
None of that made any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect a very simple reason for your troubles: indentation. Most of the times in `scss` it happens that there is no space after the statement, in your case `background:`. Try also this in your scss prefixed file:

```
background: url(dna.jpg);
```

It always works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around: turned the **scss** file into a normal css file.

**home.css**

```
body {background-image:url('dna.jpg');
      background-size:cover;}
```

Now it works fine. It doesn't seem like the right solution though.

Comment: I suspect a very simple reason for your troubles: indentation. Most of the times in scss it happens that there is no space after the statement, in your case `background:`. Try also this in your `scss` prefixed file: `background: url(dna.jpg);`. It always works for me.

Comment: @Qumara SixOneTour you are correct. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am happy when I can help. Good luck with your application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and it was a result of me using Sass Indented Syntax in an SCSS file.

More info on the differences between Sass and SCSS: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html